# Two action URLs in one jsp

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, liferay

I just want to know, if I can have two `<portlet:actionURL var="wakeup">` action urls in one jsp. Which will be called depending on a filled inputs and JS submiting this forms. Example:

**JS:**

```
function startActions() {
    if (document.getElementById("shut").checked ||
        document.getElementById("reboot").checked) {    
        document.getElementById("shutdownRebootForm").submit();
    }
    if (document.getElementById("wake").checked) {
        document.getElementById("wakeUpForm").submit();
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<portlet:actionURL var="shutdownReboot">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="shutdown-reboot" />
</portlet:actionURL>
<form id="shutdownRebootForm" method="post" action="${shutdownReboot}">
    //some HTML code
</form>

<portlet:actionURL var="wakeup">
    <portlet:param name="wakeaction" value="wakeup" />
</portlet:actionURL>
<form id="wakeUpForm" method="post" action="${wakeup}">
    //some HTML code
</form>
```

I'm using spring MVC... is this possible to implement? Will it work as expected?

Comment: Why, is there any strict need to place two form? Although you can achieve this using single!

Comment: Let's say I started to work on a project which has implemented method called from one actionURL... The easiest way is to implement another method, called from another actionURL, to avoid reimplementing the first method and divide backend code calling into two controller methods, however I want to call this method from one jsp page in portlet.

Comment: I've got an idea to divide this jsp page into separated jsps which each one will have actionURL and then just simply include one jsp to another, not sure if it'll work, but can try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Liferay Documentation:**

> You can have as many actions as you want in a portlet. Implement each
>   one as a method that receives two parameters: an `ActionRequest` and an
>   `ActionResponse`. Name the method whatever you want, but note that the
>   method name must match the URL name that points to it.

Therefore, based on suitable JSP, action and scripting structure, you can place as many actionURLs, you want in a single portlet. The important point is to match the value of `name` attribute specified on URL tag with method's name.

If you are specifying name attribute, then you need to implement separate action methods in listener class.

**Pattern 1:**

See, your actionURLs will look like following:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="shutdownRebootURL" name="shutdownReboot">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="shutdown-reboot" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<portlet:actionURL var="wakeupURL" name="wakeup">
    <portlet:param name="wakeaction" value="wakeup" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

So, your action slass should contain following methods:

```
public void shutdownReboot(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {
        // Your shutdownReboot logic goes here
}

public void wakeup(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {
        // Your wakeup logic goes here
}
```

However, there is no hard-n-fast need to put two form(s) / actionURLs, you can achieve your requirement by implementing one action method in listener class, filtered based on the parameter's value.
On each action, that parameter will identify, which action has been called.

**Pattern 2:**

Consider following example:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="<portlet:actionURL />" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="" />

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>shutdown checkbox</td>
            <td>reboot checkbox</td>
            <td>wakeup checkbox</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- show specific button based on checkbox checked -->
                <button type="submit" id="shutdownReboot" onclick="startActions('shutdownReboot');">Shutdown / Reboot</button>
                <button type="submit" id="wakeup" onclick="startActions('wakeup');">Wakeup</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function startActions(action) {
    document.getElementById('action').value = action;
    /* set other required parameters */
}
```

**Action method:**

```
String action = "";
public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {

    if(actionRequest.getParameter("action") != null && actionRequest.getParameter("action") != ""){
            action = actionRequest.getParameter(action);
    }

    if(action.equals("shutdownReboot")){
        // shutdown-reboot logic
    }else if(action.equals("wakeup")){
        // wakeup logic
    }else{
        // default logic
    }       
}
```