# Should I call super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse) in any action method in a Liferay portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Should I call super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse) in every action method I have within a Liferay portlet. If yes, why? and where this call should go (should it go to the beginning or to the end of the method body) and why?

Comment: Which class do you extend in your portlet's action class?

Comment: @ParkashKumar, I extend MVCPortlet

Comment: If you have implemented custom action class which extends `MVCPortlet`, then there is no hard and fast rule to call `super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse)`, just write your own implementation in action methods.

Comment: So this means there is no specific logic in MVCPortlet corresponding action method that I need to call. Then, I wonder what does the MVCPortlet processAction body contains? (I need to take a look at the source then! any link that I get the source of MVCPortlet?)

Comment: `processAction` is parent Class's (`MVCPortlet`) method, which is also available in your custom class. You can add it as overriden method (if you add) then leave it empty. It won't get called, if you create action URLs specifying name attribute in it, then portlet will find associated action method with that signature. See [***this***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413937/two-action-urls-in-one-jsp/29427147#29427147) for further reference.

Comment: Here is reference to [***MVCPortlet***](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/util-bridges/6.0.4/com/liferay/util/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.java) Class. There are other methods as well, which we don't override.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your requirement. If you simply want to call Super class implementation for process action, you can use super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse)  and it should be called at end because any code after this line will not executed if redirected to proessAction of MVCPortlet or GenericPortlet.